# C - "Error: Expected identifier or '(' before '[' token"

Tags: c, arrays, struct, linkage

I am making a rogue-like game in C and I am having trouble with file linkage.
I am making a custom header file where I declare an array of structures, but when I compile this code:

```
#ifndef spells
#define spells

struct spells SpellList[55];

#endif // spells
```

I get an error: Expected identifier or '(' before '[' token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the identifier `spells` for two different purposes: as a "guard macro" for the header file, and as the tag-name for a struct.  The compiler does not understand that you want these to be independent.  With the code as shown, the preprocessing stage will replace *all* uses of the identifier `spells` with nothing, and then the parsing stage will see

```
struct SpellList[55];
```

which is invalid.

You must rename either the guard macro or the struct tag.  Since you never need to refer to guard macros anywhere else, it's probably easiest to rename the guard macro.

Incidentally, "[rouge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rouge)" is a type of make-up.  The kind of game you are making is a *[rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(video_game))*-like.

Comment: I did everything like you said, but now I get and error saying: error type has incomplete element type.

Comment: @octagonlord69 Yes, that's because you have not actually provided a definition of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is using your defined symbol `spells` as a type.

Where you have:

```
struct spells SpellList[55];
```

The preprocessor will replace `spells` in that line with the value of the `spells` define (nothing) before the compiler tries to compile the code. This produces invalid code.

Comment: When you don't give a `#define`d macro a value, it expands to _nothing_, and that's not compiler-dependent at all; it's required by the C standard.